# Display image field from nid

Tags: entities, theming, media

I'm trying to print the image field from a node using the nid in the url.

$nid = $_GET['field_item_request'];

Is there a specific way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$nid = arg(1);
$node = node_load($nid);
$image = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_item_request');
$output = field_view_value('node', $node, 'field_item_request', $image[0]);
print render($output);
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction! Since I was trying to get the nid from an argument in the url I had to edit it a bit. This is what worked for me:       
      $nid = $_GET['field_item_request'];      
      $node = node_load($nid);
      $image = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_image');
      $output = field_view_value('node', $node, 'field_image', $image[0]);
      print render($output);

Comment: Sorry, It seems I dont have enough reputation to up-vote your answer.

Comment: Welcome to SO. If one of the answers above fixes your issue, you should accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer). That does two things. It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add a specific style to my image. So I modify the code above to fit my needs. Hopefully it will help somebody out.

```
  $nid = $_GET['field_item_request'];      
  $node = node_load($nid);
  $image = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_image');
  $image_output = render(field_view_value('node', $node, 'field_image', $image[0], array('settings' => array('image_style' => 'medium', 'label' => ''))));

  print render($image_output);
```